# Symfony Doctrine: One to Many relationship is deleting parent entity

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, one-to-many, symfony2-easyadmin

I have parent and child entity. After all child entities are deleted, symfony delete my parent entity too. I don't like such behavior, parent entity must exist whenever there are some children or not. Here is my code for parent:

```
    /**
     * @OneToMany(targetEntity="Gallery", mappedBy="promotion", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
     */
    private $galleries;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->galleries = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function getGalleries() {
        return $this->galleries;
    }

    public function addGallery($gallery)
    {
        $gallery->setPromotion($this);
        $this->galleries[] = $gallery;

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeGallery($gallery)
    {
        $gallery->setPromotion(null);
        $this->galleries->removeElement($gallery);
    }
```

And here for child:

```
    /**
     * @ManyToOne(targetEntity="Promotion", inversedBy="galleries")
     */

    private $promotion;
```

I don't know what to do, I have already spend hours on this.

It is handled by easy admin bundle, so it won't help you:

```
namespace AppBundle\Controller;

use JavierEguiluz\Bundle\EasyAdminBundle\Event\EasyAdminEvents;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Acl\Exception\Exception;
use AppBundle\Entity\Promotion;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse;

class PromotionController extends PageController {
    protected $folder = 'promotions';
    protected $htmlFileName = 'default-template.html';

    protected function rearangeAction() {
        $ids = json_decode($this->request->get('ids'));
        $order = 1;

        foreach($ids as $id) {            
            $this->em->createQuery('UPDATE AppBundle:Promotion p SET p.order = :order WHERE p.id = :id')
                ->setParameter('order', $order++)
                ->setParameter('id', $id)
                ->execute();
        }

        return $this->redirectToRoute('easyadmin', $this->prepareRouteParams());
    }

    protected function checkFolderAction() {        
        $row = $this->em->createQuery('SELECT p FROM AppBundle:Promotion p WHERE p.language = :language AND p.subfolder = :subfolder')
                ->setParameter('language', $this->language)
                ->setParameter('subfolder', $this->request->get('subfolder'))
                ->getOneOrNullResult();

        if($row) {
            return new JsonResponse(array('duplicity' => 1));
        } else {
            return new JsonResponse(array('duplicity' => 0));
        }
    }

    protected function deleteFiles($databaseSubFolders) {
        $mainFolder = $this->baseDir.'/'.$this->folder.'/'.$this->language;

        $databaseSubFolders[] = '..';
        $databaseSubFolders[] = '.';

        $subFolders = array_diff(scandir($mainFolder), $databaseSubFolders);

        foreach($subFolders as $subFolder) {
            $this->deleteFolder($mainFolder.'/'.$subFolder);
        }
    }

    protected function exportAction() {
        $query = $this->em->createQuery('SELECT p FROM AppBundle:Promotion p WHERE p.language = :language')
                ->setParameter('language', $this->language);

        $subFolders = array();

        foreach($query->getArrayResult() as $key => $val) {
            $subFolders[] = $val['subfolder'];

            //  pridanie novych a uprava starych

            $image = basename($val['headerImage']);
            $imageName = substr($image, 0 ,strpos($image,'.'));

            $all = '<div class="header">
                        <div class="row">
                            <h2>
                                '.$val['headerTitle'].'
                            </h2>
                            <p>
                                '.$val['headerTeaser'].'
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </div><img src="{{::promo.imgPath}}/'.$image.'" alt="'.$imageName.'">';

            $all .= $this->changeMarkdownToHtml($val['html']);
            $all .= $this->changeMarkdownToHtml($val['terms']);

            file_put_contents($this->baseDir.'/'.$this->folder.'/'.$this->language.'/'.$val['subfolder'].'/html/'.$val['filename'], $all);
        }

        //  zmazanie starych zloziek

        $this->deleteFiles($subFolders);        

        parent::exportAction();

        return $this->redirectToRoute('easyadmin', $this->prepareRouteParams());
    }

    private function actualImage($id, $i) {
        $row = $this->em->createQuery('SELECT p FROM AppBundle:Promotion p WHERE p.id = :id')
                ->setParameter('id', $id)
                ->getOneOrNullResult();

        return call_user_func_array(array($row,'getImage'.$i), array());
    }

    protected function preDeleteEntity($id) {
        //  mazanie obrazkov


    }

    protected function preSearchEntity($entity) {
        $entity['search']['dql_filter'] = "entity.language = '".$this->language."'";

        return $entity;
    }

    protected function prePersistEntity($entity) {
        //  ukladanie dalsich dat

        $entity->setLanguage($this->language);
        $entity->setFilename($this->htmlFileName);

        $row = $this->em->createQuery('SELECT MAX(p.order)+1 FROM AppBundle:Promotion p')
                ->getOneOrNullResult();

        $entity->setOrder($row[1]);

        return $entity;
    }

    protected function postPersistEntity($entity) {
        if(!is_dir($this->baseDir.'/'.$this->folder.'/'.$this->language.'/'.$entity->getSubfolder())) {                
            mkdir($this->baseDir.'/'.$this->folder.'/'.$this->language.'/'.$entity->getSubfolder());
            mkdir($this->baseDir.'/'.$this->folder.'/'.$this->language.'/'.$entity->getSubfolder().'/'.'header');
            mkdir($this->baseDir.'/'.$this->folder.'/'.$this->language.'/'.$entity->getSubfolder().'/'.'html');
            mkdir($this->baseDir.'/'.$this->folder.'/'.$this->language.'/'.$entity->getSubfolder().'/'.'img');
        }

        //  presun obrazkov

        $images = array();

        foreach($entity->getGalleries()->getSnapshot() as $snapshot) {
            $image = $snapshot->getImage();

            $from = $this->get('kernel')->getRootDir().'/../web/uploads/temp/'.basename($image);
            $to = $this->baseDir.'/'.$this->folder.'/'.$this->language.'/'.$entity->getSubfolder().'/img/'.$image;

            $this->copyFile($from, $to);

            $images[] = $image;
        }

        $getImage = $entity->getHeaderImage();

        $from = $this->get('kernel')->getRootDir().'/../web/uploads/temp/'.basename($getImage);
        $to = $this->baseDir.'/'.$this->folder.'/'.$this->language.$getImage;

        $this->copyFile($from, $to);

        $entity->setHtml($this->replaceImages($entity->getHtml(), $images));

        return $entity;
    }

    protected function preRemoveEntity($entity) {
        //if($_POST['_method'] != 'DELETE') {
//            var_dump($entity);
//            die();
        //}

        return $entity;
    }

    protected function editAction() {    
        $id = $this->request->query->get('id');

        $this->dispatch(EasyAdminEvents::PRE_EDIT);
        $this->executeDynamicMethod('preEdit<EntityName>Entity', array($id));

        $easyadmin = $this->request->attributes->get('easyadmin');
        $entity = $easyadmin['item'];        

        if ($this->request->isXmlHttpRequest() && $property = $this->request->query->get('property')) {
            $newValue = 'true' === mb_strtolower($this->request->query->get('newValue'));
            $fieldsMetadata = $this->entity['list']['fields'];

            if (!isset($fieldsMetadata[$property]) || 'toggle' !== $fieldsMetadata[$property]['dataType']) {
                throw new \RuntimeException(sprintf('The type of the "%s" property is not "toggle".', $property));
            }

            $this->updateEntityProperty($entity, $property, $newValue);

            return new Response((string) $newValue);
        }

        $fields = $this->entity['edit']['fields'];

        $editForm = $this->executeDynamicMethod('create<EntityName>EditForm', array($entity, $fields));

        $deleteForm = $this->createDeleteForm($this->entity['name'], $id);

        //  kontrola pre presun

        $row = $this->em->createQuery('SELECT p FROM AppBundle:Promotion p WHERE p.id = :id')
                    ->setParameter('id', $id)
                    ->getOneOrNullResult();

        $previousSubfolder = $row->getSubfolder();

        $editForm->handleRequest($this->request);

        if ($editForm->isSubmitted() && $editForm->isValid()) {
            $this->dispatch(EasyAdminEvents::PRE_UPDATE, array('entity' => $entity));            
            $entity = $this->executeDynamicMethod('preUpdate2<EntityName>Entity', array($entity,$previousSubfolder));

            $this->em->flush();

            $this->dispatch(EasyAdminEvents::POST_UPDATE, array('entity' => $entity));            
            $entity = $this->executeDynamicMethod('postUpdate2<EntityName>Entity', array($entity,$previousSubfolder));

            $refererUrl = $this->request->query->get('referer', '');           

            return !empty($refererUrl)
                ? $this->redirect(urldecode($refererUrl))
                : $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('easyadmin', array('action' => 'list', 'entity' => $this->entity['name'])));
        }

        $this->dispatch(EasyAdminEvents::POST_EDIT);        
        $entity = $this->executeDynamicMethod('postEdit<EntityName>Entity', array($entity));

        return $this->render($this->entity['templates']['edit'], array(
            'form' => $editForm->createView(),
            'entity_fields' => $fields,
            'entity' => $entity,
            'delete_form' => $deleteForm->createView(),
        ));
    }

    protected function preUpdate2Entity($entity, $previousSubfolder) {


//        if($_POST['delete_form']['_easyadmin_delete_flag'] == 1) {
//            $this->em->createQuery('DELETE FROM AppBundle:Gallery g WHERE g.promotion = :id')
//                    ->setParameter('id', $id)
//                    ->execute();
//        }


        $images = array();        

        foreach($entity->getGalleries()->getSnapshot() as $snapshot) {
            $image = $snapshot->getImage();

            $images[] = $image;
        }



        $entity->setHtml($this->replaceImages($entity->getHtml(), $images));

        return $entity;
    }

    protected function postUpdate2Entity($entity, $previousSubfolder) {
        if(!is_dir($this->baseDir.'/'.$this->folder.'/'.$this->language.'/'.$entity->getSubfolder())) {                
            mkdir($this->baseDir.'/'.$this->folder.'/'.$this->language.'/'.$entity->getSubfolder());
            mkdir($this->baseDir.'/'.$this->folder.'/'.$this->language.'/'.$entity->getSubfolder().'/'.'header');
            mkdir($this->baseDir.'/'.$this->folder.'/'.$this->language.'/'.$entity->getSubfolder().'/'.'html');
            mkdir($this->baseDir.'/'.$this->folder.'/'.$this->language.'/'.$entity->getSubfolder().'/'.'img');
        }

        //  presun obrazkov

        $images = array();

        foreach($entity->getGalleries()->getSnapshot() as $snapshot) {
            $image = $snapshot->getImage();

            $from = $this->get('kernel')->getRootDir().'/../web/uploads/temp/'.basename($image);
            $to = $this->baseDir.'/'.$this->folder.'/'.$this->language.'/'.$entity->getSubfolder().'/img/'.$image;

            if(!file_exists($from)) {                  
                $from = $this->baseDir.'/'.$this->folder.'/'.$this->language.'/'.$previousSubfolder.'/img/'.$image;
            }

            $this->copyFile($from, $to);
            $images[] = $image;
        }

        //  zmazanie obrazkov

        $folderImages = array_diff(scandir($this->baseDir.'/'.$this->folder.'/'.$this->language.'/'.$previousSubfolder.'/img/'), array('..', '.'));

        foreach($folderImages as $folderImage) {
            if(!in_array($folderImage, $images)) {
                unlink($this->baseDir.'/'.$this->folder.'/'.$this->language.'/'.$previousSubfolder.'/img/'.$folderImage);
            }
        }

        $getImage = $entity->getHeaderImage();

        $from = $this->get('kernel')->getRootDir().'/../web/uploads/temp/'.basename($getImage);

        if(!file_exists($from)) {
            $from = $this->baseDir.'/'.$this->folder.'/'.$this->language.$getImage;
        }

        $to = $this->baseDir.'/'.$this->folder.'/'.$this->language.'/'.$entity->getSubfolder().'/header/'.basename($getImage);

        $this->copyFile($from, $to);

        return $entity;
    }

    protected function postEditEntity($entity) {
        //  cesta pre obrazky        

        $entity->setHeaderImage(null, '/uploads/'.$this->container->getParameter('repo.folder').'/'.$this->folder.'/'.$this->language.$entity->getHeaderImage());

        return $entity;
    }

    protected function preListEntity($entity) {
        $entity['list']['dql_filter'] = "entity.language = '".$this->language."'";

        return $entity;
    }

    protected function postListEntity($fields) {
        //  cesta pre obrazky        

        $fields['headerImage']['base_path'] = '/uploads/'.$this->container->getParameter('repo.folder').'/'.$this->folder.'/'.$this->language;

        return $fields;
    }

    protected function postSearchEntity($fields) {
        //  cesta pre obrazky

        $fields['headerImage']['base_path'] = '/uploads/'.$this->container->getParameter('repo.folder').'/'.$this->folder.'/'.$this->language;

        return $fields;
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you try to delete the property cascade?

Comment: [Bidirectional one-to-many cascade remove and orphanRemoval operations in doctrine](http://www.inanzzz.com/index.php/post/ur2x/bidirectional-one-to-many-cascade-remove-and-orphan-removal-operations-in-doctrine)

Comment: I have already tried it, result is:

The entity may have been deleted by mistake or by a "cascade={"remove"}" operation executed by Doctrine.

Comment: Please post your controller

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove cascade annotation at all. The rest looks good.